# format date column when update query

Tags: php, date, wamp

my date type is `date` and the data is `2010-08-01` I convert from Y-m-d to d-m-Y when echo
output - `01-08-2010`

echo code

```
<td width="50%" class="pk_2"><input name="personal_ic_from" type="text" class="tcal" id="personal_ic_from" value="<?php
echo date_create($personal_ic_from)->format('d-m-Y');
?>" readonly="readonly"/>
          </td>
```

what should I add on my update query to convert from d-m-Y to Y-m-d. I found that my database cant store the new date data because the database format is `date` `Y-m-d`

update code

```
<?php 
$personal_ic_from = $_POST['personal_ic_from'];
mysql_query("UPDATE personal_id_ic SET personal_ic_from = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["personal_ic_from"])."'  WHERE LAS_login_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["LAS_login_id"])."'");
?>
```

Comment: You might consider leaving all the dates in the same format on the frontend, then have the server convert them before storage or after reading to present to the client.

Comment: @TimSPQR I required by my lecturer to use date format in database, then echo with d-m-Y format, and then update with Y-m-d format. so far, echo is good. but i got problem when update. its will be much easier if is just use varchar on date column right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).
Your query should look like this,

```
mysql_query("UPDATE personal_id_ic SET personal_ic_from = STR_TO_DATE('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["personal_ic_from"])."','%Y-%m-%d')  WHERE LAS_login_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["LAS_login_id"])."'");
```

Comment: i got this Fatal error: Call to undefined function STR_TO_DATE() in C:\wamp\www\eprofile\process.php on line 51. how can i defined that function?

Comment: Ok I got it now. u forgot to change '%Y-%m-%d' to '%d-%m-%Y'.. When i change it to '%d-%m-%Y' it working.. I use this mysql_query("UPDATE personal_id_ic SET personal_ic_from = STR_TO_DATE('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["personal_ic_from"])."','%Y-%m-%d')  WHERE LAS_login_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["LAS_login_id"])."'"); Thx for your help Mr. Deepak

Answer (score 0):

just use STR_TO_DATE function in your query it's mysql function.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

"UPDATE personal_id_ic SET personal_ic_from = STR_TO_DATE('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["personal_ic_from"])."','%d-%m-%Y')  WHERE LAS_login_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["LAS_login_id"])."'";

Comment: i got this Fatal error: Call to undefined function STR_TO_DATE() in C:\wamp\www\eprofile\process.php on line 51. how can i defined that function?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
 $personal_ic_from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['personal_ic_from']));
 mysql_query("UPDATE personal_id_ic SET personal_ic_from = '".mysql_real_escape_string($personal_ic_from)."'  WHERE LAS_login_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["LAS_login_id"])."'");
?>
```

Try this. This will solves your issue.

Comment: i try your code, but when i choose different date and try to run update query, data of the date that store at database is '0000-00-00'

Answer (score 0):

I've recently learned about "explode" on this forum and have implemented it like this:

```
$frontenddob = $POST['dob'];    
list ($m, $d, $y) = explode('/', $frontenddob);    
$dob = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $y, $m, $d);
```

You can use it to convert between date formats, and don't run into the problems with strtotime date limits.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code
<?php 
$personal_ic_from = $_POST['personal_ic_from'];
$personalDate=date_create($personal_ic_from);
$pdate=date_format($personalDate,"d-m-Y");

mysql_query("UPDATE personal_id_ic SET personal_ic_from ='".mysql_real_escape_string($pdate)."'  WHERE LAS_login_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["LAS_login_id"])."'");

?>
```

Comment: i try your code, but when i choose different date and try to run update query, data of the date that store at database is '0000-00-00'. can u tell me why that happen and any suggestion ?

Comment: Check your post date $_POST['personal_ic_from'];